# Java, Websockets, tyrus server: handshake error

Tags: java, websocket

ServerApp:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import org.glassfish.tyrus.server.Server;

public class ServerApp {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        ServerApp server = new ServerApp();
        server.runServer();
    }

    public void runServer() {
        Server server = new Server("localhost", 8025, "/websocket", null, ServerEndPoint.class);

        try {
            server.start();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            System.out.print("Please press a key to stop the server.");
            reader.readLine();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
        server.stop();
        }
    }
}
```

ServerEndPoint:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.websocket.CloseReason;
import javax.websocket.CloseReason.CloseCodes;
import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

@ServerEndpoint(value = "/game")
public class ServerEndPoint {

    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) {
        System.out.println("Connected ... " + session.getId());

    }

    @OnMessage
    public String onMessage(String message, Session session) {
        System.out.println("onMessage: "+message);
        switch (message) {
        case "quit":
            try {
                session.close(new CloseReason(CloseCodes.NORMAL_CLOSURE, "Game ended"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            break;
        }
        return message;
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session, CloseReason closeReason) {
        System.out.println("onClose: "+String.format("Session %s closed because of %s", session.getId(), closeReason));
        logger.info(String.format("Session %s closed because of %s", session.getId(), closeReason));
    }
}
```

this works greatly, server starts and waits the client.

ClientApp:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import javax.websocket.ClientEndpoint;
import javax.websocket.DeploymentException;
import org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager;

@ClientEndpoint
public class ClientApp {
    public static CountDownLatch latch;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        ClientManager client = ClientManager.createClient();
        try {
            client.connectToServer(ClientApp.class, new URI("ws://localhost:8025/websockets/game"));
            latch.await();

        } catch (DeploymentException | URISyntaxException | InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

ClientEndPoint:

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.websocket.ClientEndpoint;
import javax.websocket.CloseReason;
import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;

@ClientEndpoint
public class ClientEndPoint {

    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) {
        // same as above
        System.out.println("onOpen");
    }

    @OnMessage
    public String onMessage(String message, Session session) {
        // same as above
        System.out.println("onMessage");
        return "";
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session, CloseReason closeReason) {
        System.out.println("onClose");
        logger.info(String.format("Session %s close because of %s", session.getId(), closeReason));
        ClientApp.latch.countDown();
    }
}
```

and when I try to connect: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.websocket.DeploymentException: Handshake error.`

I have no clue what makes it.

Trace log:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.websocket.DeploymentException: Handshake error.
    at *.websocket.client.ClientApp.main(ClientApp.java:23)
Caused by: javax.websocket.DeploymentException: Handshake error.
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager$1$1.run(ClientManager.java:552)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager$1.run(ClientManager.java:582)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(ClientManager.java:734)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager.connectToServer(ClientManager.java:431)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager.connectToServer(ClientManager.java:267)
    at *.websocket.client.ClientApp.main(ClientApp.java:19)
Caused by: org.glassfish.tyrus.core.HandshakeException: Response code was not 101: 404.
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.Handshake.validateServerResponse(Handshake.java:194)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.TyrusClientEngine.processResponse(TyrusClientEngine.java:142)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.client.GrizzlyClientFilter.handleHandshake(GrizzlyClientFilter.java:326)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.client.GrizzlyClientFilter.handleRead(GrizzlyClientFilter.java:296)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: whats the stack trace?

Comment: I added, but it wont help much